# How do you get Angular to display Visa Credit / Debit when you auto fill card numbers from Chrome

Tags: angular

When I use auto fill for cards in Chrome and select Visa Debit it displays the card type as Visa and not Visa Debit. The HTML displayed Visa Credit / Visa Debit before we changed to Angular

I've tried changing the input type to 'text' as this was used in the old site but this didn't fix the issue (I'm not sure why it has been setup as input type 'tel' but guess there was a reason for this).

I current have:

```html
<input type="tel" class="form-control w-100" formControlName='cardNumber' maxlength="23">
```

I expect the card type to auto populate Visa Debit or Visa Credit when entering/selecting the card.

Comment: Welcome to SO, there is not enough code in your question.

Comment: You might want to have a look at [Google's Docs](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/06/checkout-faster-with-autofill) on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue in the end by changing the names of the keys to ensure all Visa related cards quoted 'Visa'. I'm guessing Chrome requires this for the auto complete to work.

Comment: Would you be able to provide an example? I'm trying to get auto completion for credit card info to work in my Angular app

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Google Docs](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/06/checkout-faster-with-autofill) you might need to add `autocomplete="cc-number"` to the field so that it auto-completes the credit card number for you correctly.

The whole input for the credit card number would look something like this:

```
<input name="cardnumber" id="frmCCNum" required autocomplete="cc-number">
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried this but this didn't work I still get Visa Credit for both Visa Credit and Visa Debit